# iOS Firebase Crashlytics missing dSYM

Tags: ios, firebase, crashlytics

So I am trying to use Google Firebase Crashlytics

I have followed any steps from

https://docs.fabric.io/apple/crashlytics/missing-dsyms.html
    https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/upgrade-from-crash-reporting

But it is still not working with Firebase Crashlytics

My application "Set Bitcode" is set to NO

I have tried to set my "Debug Information Format" in the Build Settings to "DWARF with dSYM"

I have tried to get the dSYM manually from "Show package content" on my archived app(same version of app), compressed it to zip, and uploaded it to Firebase Crashlytics. It showed upload successfull, but the missing dSYM message is still there.

My previous uploaded dSYM is not shown on the Firebase dashboard(I am not sure this is intended or not)

So basically my crash is submitted to the Firebase Crashlytics but it couldn't get the dSYM.

Can anyone guide me on how to use it?

Comment: Mike from Firebase here. If you run dwarfdump -u <PathToDsym> does the UUID of the dSYM you're uploading match the one reported as missing?

Comment: Hi Mike, I am new to the development, could you please elaborate on how i run the command above? Can i just run it in terminal? And how can i get the path to the dSYM? thanks

Comment: Yep, run it in terminal on your macOS box and for the path, you can just drag the dSYM into the terminal and the path will be added.

Comment: hi Sir, sorry for my late reply. Yes there is one UUID in my package content dsym that matches the UUID in fiirebase (missing dSYM). Is there anything i need to do? thanks

Comment: Hmm, that should have done the trick then. I'd recommend contacting Firebase support and provide the dSYM as well.

Comment: i have tried with several apps, and also the same problem occurs. Thanks sir for your help!

Answer (score 17):

I solved the missing dSYM issue by following steps.

1. Under Build phase add the run script as below image
   [image: Adding run script]
2. Under build settings **enable bitcode to Yes** and **Debug information format** to **DWARF with dSYM File** as below
   [image: DWARF with dSYM File]
3. Upload dSYM manually using terminal as below

(3.1) Open terminal

(3.2) Under Xcode Project -> Pods -> FirebaseCrashlytics folder -> Right click -> Show in Finder , there you will find **Upload_Symbols** file as below images
[image: FirebaseCrashlytics]
[image: Upload_Symbols]

(3.3)Drag & Drop **upload-symbols** file into terminal
[image: Drag & Drop upload-symbols]

(3.4)Enter **-gsp** in terminal with single space on both sides

(3.5)Locate **GoogleService-Info.plist** file in xcode project. Drag & drop **GoogleService-Info.plist** into terminal as below
[image: GoogleService-Info.plist]

(3.6)Enter **-p ios** in terminal with single space on both sides

(3.7)Locate **app.dSYM** file as below
Xcode -> Windows -> Organizer -> Select Archive -> Right Click -> Show in finder -> Select Archive -> Right Click -> Show package contents -> dSYMs -> Select **app.dSYM**

(3.8)Drag & Drop **app.dSYM** file into terminal as below
[image: app.dSYM]

(3.9)Enter, you will get message in console as below
[image: Success]

(3.10)Try to uninstall & install the app in the device, please check after sometime, the issue in firebase will be resolved

Answer (score 6):

in your Xcode project, under Build Phases
add below run script:

```
"${PODS_ROOT}/Fabric/upload-symbols" -gsp "${PROJECT_DIR}/GoogleService-Info.plist" -p ios "${DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH}/${DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME}"
```

[image: here is a image]

Comment: is it necessary to select checkbox of "Show environment variables in build log" ?

Comment: @iNiravKotecha I don’t think so, it was checked by default

Answer (score 4):

Add following scripts in the build phase:

```
${PODS_ROOT}/Fabric/run
```

Input files:

```
$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/$(INFOPLIST_PATH)
$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/${GOOGLE_INFO_PLIST_PATH}
${DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH}/${DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME}/Contents/Resources/DWARF/${TARGET_NAME}
```

Add user defined setting:

```
GOOGLE_INFO_PLIST_PATH:     ${SRCROOT}/GoogleService-Info.plist
```

For below script :
**Do not** check *run script only when installing* option

```
${PODS_ROOT}/Fabric/upload-symbols -gsp ${GOOGLE_INFO_PLIST_PATH} -p ios ${DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH}/${DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME}
```

If you're using new `FirebaseCrashlytics`, replace `Fabric` with `FirebaseCrashlytics` in your script